# Groovy collect() closure not working to capitalize strings

Tags: string, groovy, closures

I have a list of objects that are not necessarily a string, and I want to return a list of strings that have been capitalized.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
// Input : ["foo", "bar"] (not actually strings)
// Expected Output : ["Foo", "Bar"]
// Actual Output : ["foo", "bar"]

// Code: 
list.collect { it.toString().capitalize() }
```

What might be the problem? If I print out each element as I go trough collect it prints the correct values, but the final list is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collect` doesn't mutate the original list, but returns a new one:

```
def oringinal = ["foo", "bar"]
def capitalized = original.collect { it.capitalize() }
println(capitalized) // ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

PS: you can also use the `*.` spread-dot operator like so:

```
def capitalized = original*.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 1):

You suspect that `.collect()` method mutates input list, but it **does not** - it creates a copy of the list and does not change anything in the input list.

```
def list = ["foo", "bar"]

def newList = list.collect { it.toString().capitalize() }

assert list != newList

assert newList == ["Foo", "Bar"]
```